# Trying to use TextView as a button to move to another activity in ExpendableListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, expandablelistview

I want to go to my secondActivity when i click on the drop down list values from the ExpendableListView. i have seen examples to show toast messages but none to move to another activity.I am quite new to android.please tell me how can i do that. i have tried intent class also.thanks in advance.

This is my secondActivity.java file

```
package com.example.android.infoline;  

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;  
import android.os.Bundle;  

public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {  

    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);  
    }

}
```

secondActivity.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCancer1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCancer2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtCancer1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Tooltip"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

ExpandableListViewAdapter.java file

```
package com.example.android.infoline;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ExpandableListViewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter implements View.OnClickListener{


    String[] MainTopics = {"Health", "Network","Bank"};
    String[][] subTopics = {{"Cancer","Depression","Diabeties","Rape","Road Accident"
    ,"HIV", "Periods"},{"Vodaphone","Airtel"},{"SBI","PNB","HDFC"}};

    Context context;

    public ExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return MainTopics.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return subTopics[groupPosition].length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return MainTopics[groupPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

        return subTopics[groupPosition][childPosition];
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    //to return the main topics
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView txtview = new TextView(context);
        txtview.setText(MainTopics[groupPosition]);
        txtview.setPadding(100,0,0,0);
        txtview.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        txtview.setTextSize(40);
        return txtview;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        TextView txtview = new TextView(context);
        txtview.setText(subTopics[groupPosition][childPosition]);
        txtview.setPadding(100,0,0,0);
        txtview.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
        txtview.setTextSize(40);
        txtview.setOnClickListener(this);
        //txtview.setOnClickListener(Toast.makeText(context,txtview.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(););

        return txtview;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What challenge are you facing? I can roughly see there is a code to go to another activity....!

Comment: in ExpendableListView, from getChildView i want to use each textbox as an button to go to another activity. is it clear not ?? what extra file you want ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onClick(View v)` method, write:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

If you want to retrieve the text from the clicked button, write:

```
// optionally, check if the view is an instance of TextView
String text = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
```

If you want to pass the string to `SecondActivity`, write:

```
intent.putExtra(SOME_CONSTANT, text);
```

and to retrieve it in `SecondActivity`, write:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String text = intent.getStringExtra(SOME_CONSTANT);
```

One last thing: make sure your `SecondActivity` is not just a transparent background with empty `TextView`s

Comment: can u tell me how can i check the text passing when i click on the childListView or you can say dropdown. because after using context , every time i click on any list item , its going to the same activity .so i need to access the value of the child passing for using switch case. @Ace

Comment: I just noticed that your code was in the adapter, for some reason I thought it was in the activity. Anyway, since you already have a reference to `context`, all you have to do is, simply replace `this` in the first code snippet with `context`. I'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: As for your new question, I answered it for you yesterday before you ask it. Check the 2nd and 3rd code snippets in my answer. Put that code in your `onClick()` method before `startActivity()`.
I don't get why you accepted that answer if this is more helpful to you.

Comment: in the beginning, i tried it but for some reason it didn't worked. now , i see you said the same thing. thank you.

Comment: I'm glad it worked, I hope you got an answer to all your questions

Answer (score 0):

As you had not passed context to intent it is not working.In adapter you need to pass Context .

Try below Code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49998683/6920195

Comment: your answer helped .all i had to do is use context. @RohanLodhi 
   Intent intent = new Intent();
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class));

Comment: how can i check the value of the list from my OnClick method ? using Log then what to mention inside ?

Comment: @SidharthK.Burnwal can you tell in detail.Did u want to get the value of textview .Declare textview globally.