# Why intent is not passed from adapter class?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

Actually I'm trying to pass intent from adapter class on click of item . Although it may sound a normal or foolish question but I'm stuck in it from last 3 4 days . At first I was thinking that the `itemView` is not receiving the click but then I tried to put a toast inside the `onClick()` method but the strange part is it's toasting the message without any problem or error but it's not passing intent . I don't know why this strange behavior is happening . I've tried to search a lot of questions in **SO** but none of them were helpful.

Code:

```
 //opening img on clik
        holder.itemView.setClickable(true);
        holder.itemView.setFocusable(true);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx,"testing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("what", "show_post");
                b.putString("timelineData", gson.toJson(totalList));
                b.putInt("position",holder.getAdapterPosition());
                Intent i = new Intent(ctx, ProfileHolder.class);
                i.putExtras(b);
                i.putExtra("Open", "starred");
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                ctx.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you show more of your code? We need more context.

Comment: What is `ProfileHolder`? Does it `extend Activity` or `extend AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it's extending AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- remove `i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` you don't need that
- is `ProfileHolder` an Activity? It doesn't seem to be one.
- if `ProfileHolder` is really an Activity, check that it is registered in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Make interface between adapter and activity its best way to pass intent
usefull link: 
"https://github.com/Androidsignal/Android-Retrofit"
see in ada

Answer (score 0):

**I think you are not passing context properly.**

**Do Below steps:**
*1.Declare Context globally in the adapter.*

```
Context context;
```

*2.In onCreateViewHolder write below code.*

```
 context = viewGroup.getContext();
```

*3.Now on click*

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, Activity.class);
```